# PIG - SET yarn garbage collection

Tags: apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to set following properties in a Pig script:

```
mapreduce.reduce.java.opts="-Xmx6114m  -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"

yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts="-Xmx6114m  -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"
```

As

```
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts -Xmx6114m  -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps;

SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts -Xmx6114m  -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps;
```

But it throws an error 
`ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: null`

Is this the wrong way to set param while
`SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts -Xmx6114m;` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enclose them with single quote.

```
SET yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts '-Xmx6114m  -XX:+UseG1GC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps'
```